# Console Application text always on top

Tags: c#, console

I need help making something that is always on top of the console application.
The problem is that I don't know how to restore the cursor position to the bottom to write normal text.

For example, imagine a screen...

```
\[This text is always here!!!]

hello

hello

...

Wassup?
```

Something like the green part that steam uses:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Console.CursorTop and Console.CursorLeft properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft.aspx